# Bing map & Hub Windows Store App Theme

Tags: c#, windows, bing

Hello i want to place the Bing Map in the 1st HubSection but i get a very small box containing the map instead of having the whole Section.

```
<HubSection Width="780" Margin="0,0,80,0">
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
         <bm:MapCredentials="key" x:Name="myMap" MapType="Aerial" ZoomLevel="9.5">
         <bm:Map.Center>
            <bm:Location Latitude="35.1" Longitude="33.33333333" />
         </bm:Map.Center>
         </bm:Map>
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: please show more code

Comment: The only thing i changed from the Hub Template is this section and also i put xmlns:bm="using:Bing:Maps" in the page tag.

Comment: remove "Width="780" Margin="0,0,80,0""

Comment: same thing but now the next Section is closer to the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone still interested in this I have found the solution:

```
        <HubSection Width="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataTemplate>
                <bm:Map Credentials="INSERT_YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY" x:Name="myMap"></bm:Map>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

It wasn't that hard after all